# Why string date is equal to 0

Tags: php

I just wondering below code ! I had never seen and heard before .Why string `date` is equal to `0` ? Is there any documentation for that..

```
<?php
$p = "date";
$n = 0;
$m = 1;
var_dump($p == $n);//true
var_dump($p == $m);//false
var_dump($n == $m);//false
?>
```

Comment: use === to get false in the first case. And read about comparing in php

Comment: Is that mean `string` is always equal to `0` ?  @splash58

Comment: For future reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp/80649#80649

Comment: when cast 'date' to int what  another result do you expect?

Comment: adn try `$p = "2date";`

Comment: Yes there is documentation: [Read](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [Learn](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you compare string with int so string is converted to int first. int from "date" string is 0

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works:

Reference : [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) [See the table]

> **Loose comparisons with ==**
>   `"PHP" == 0` is `true`
>   `"PHP" == 1` is `false`
>
> **Strict comparisons with ===**
>   `"PHP" === 0` is `false`
>   `"PHP" === 1` is `false`

So is your case with `"date"`

Answer (score 0):

See this

you have used `==`

0 is an `int`, so in this case it is going to convert `'date'` into int. Which is not parseable as one, and will become `0`. that is why you are getting `true`. try `===` opertor